# Mysql returns same rows when sending fast request

Tags: php, mysql

I discerned that sometimes Mysql returns totally same data (occasionally). i.g: https://prnt.sc/10ppiyf

I have a basic Php pdo query to get Mysql rows for my pagination:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT * from posts order by id desc LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");
```

I send total 1000 pagination requests in a loop, every 500 ms (to test system). My test url is, localhost/test.php?page=1 (page increasingly goes on in a loop up to 1000). App server and db server run on diffirent server. In this secenerio, the answer of request returns returns same rows/results (sometimes).

**If app and db run on the same Vps**, each request's answer is unique (as it should be). or **if i raised the ms (500 to 1500)**, again each request's answer is unique.

how can i understand datas are duplicate or not?
Php saves answer of request datas a file and I check it (https://prnt.sc/10ppiyf).

System details;

- Mysql posts table (innodb) have +10K rows.
- DB and script run on diffrent Vps.
- Vps are Ubuntu and, Mysql is a default installed db ( there is no any private conf).
- This DB and app are not used by anyone. Just I, use for reading data (no inserting),
- When test script was running, I control the machine Cpu and Ram was okay (%1).

How works my test case;

- A node script sends a request to app server like localhost.com/test.php?page=1  (https://prnt.sc/10ps4ey)
- App server gets page param and, sends a
- query to db server, db server sends answer and, app server saves data
- answer a file. then, i check the file.

If you want to see my php codes;

```
// request is sent by me automatically each 500 ms order by order 1,2,3,4
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
if(!$page or $page == 0)
    $page   = 1;

$perPage        = 10;
$limit          = 10;

$offset         = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage;
    
$pdo            = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=db', "user", "userp");
$pdo->query("SELECT * from posts  order by id DESC LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}");
$posts          = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What is your solution dear experienced friends?

**UPDATE:**

I use CloudFlare proxy (protection) front of my web site. If I disable CloudFlare Proxy, the number of duplicate data is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

When rows are inserted or deleted between the time that a user looks at the next/previous row, that happens.

The solution is to avoid `OFFSET`.

Here's my discussion of such: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: Thank you but my problem was not related to this point. Because I used another database and table to test system. there is no any inserting or deleting. 
Finally, I guess, found the problem partly. I use CloudFlare proxy (protection) front of my web site. If I disable the number of duplicate data is decreasing. I'm stuck!! :(